# For any $q\in [0,1]$ there exist $p>0$ such that $q(1+p)=1$

Tags: calculus

I was reading *what is mathematics* and to prove that if $q$ is a number between $0$ and $1$ then $q^n$ tends to $0$, they use that $q$ can be written as $q=\frac{1}{1+p}$ with $p>0$.

> It's equivalent to: 
>   for any $q\in (0,1)$ there exist $p>0$ such that $q(1+p)=1$.

If I have a number, such as $8/10$ I can find such a $p$, but not sure how can I proceed to prove it in 'general'.

Comment: You say for any $q\in \color{red}{[}0,1]$.  That is for any $q$ with $0\color{red}{\leq} q \leq 1$.  This is either an error or a very immediate answer that it is false.  What happens if $q=0$?  if $q=1$?

Comment: If you solve for $p$ from $q(1+p)=1$ you get (do work it out!) $p=1/q-1$. Can you show why this is $>0$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I was thinking it's a circular argument if fact, silly me.

Comment: @JMoravitz right, it's $(0,1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From
$q = \frac1{1+p}$,
we get
$p = \frac1{q}-1$.

Since
$0 < q < 1$,
$\infty > \frac1{q} > 1$,
so
$\frac1{q}-1 > 0$,
so
$p$ is well-defined.

Comment: I should have seen this argument , I am ashamed.

Answer (score 0):

How about just solving the equation?

$$q(1+p)=1$$
$$1+p = \frac{1}{q}$$
$$ p=\frac{1}{q}-1$$

Of course this doesn't work for $q=0$ (division by zero) or $q=1$ (then $p =0 \not \gt 0$) , but in those cases, the statement is clearly false.

Thus, for $q \in (0,1)$, we know that $\frac{1}{q}>1$, so $p=\frac{1}{q}-1>0$.

Answer (score 0):

For $q\in[0,1)$, we can write it as $\frac1k$ for $k\in(1,\infty)$, and when we exponentiate, it is easy to see that $k^{n+1}$ is greater than $k^{n}$ and thus $k\rightarrow \infty \implies q\rightarrow0$.

Comment: Just because it's greater doesn't mean that it goes to infinity. You have to prove that, for any $M > 0$, there is an $n$ such that $k^n > M$. The $(1+p)^n$ argument, combined with Bernoulli's inequality (so that $(1+p)^n \ge 1+np > np$) and the axiom of Archimedes, gives you what you want.